# Centering a hamburger nav styled with pseudo before/after selectors

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have a hamburger nav where its top and bottom bars are generated via pseudo before/after selectors. The issue occurs when trying to center it inside a parent element. Although the pseudo selectors center the original div element does not.

**HTML**

```
<a class="nav-container" href="##">
  <div class="hamburger"></div>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
 text-align: center;
}

* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav-container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.hamburger {
  background: black;  
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;  
  height: 5px;
  width: 30px;
}
.hamburger:before {
  background: #000;  
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
}
.hamburger:after {
  background: #000;  
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ht1d7y9f/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think it's the pseudo elements that are out of position.

```
.hamburger:before {
  background: #000;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
}
.hamburger:after {
  background: #000;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
}
```

```css
html {
  text-align: center;
}
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.nav-container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.hamburger {
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  height: 5px;
  width: 30px;
}
.hamburger:before {
  background: #000;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
}
.hamburger:after {
  background: #000;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a class="nav-container" href="##">
  <div class="hamburger"></div>
</a>
```